# AMC's in India support Direct Plan Mutual Funds for NREs

Tags: india, mutual-funds, non-resident

What are the **Bank** based AMC's in India support Direct Plan Mutual Funds for NREs ? I gone through AXIS and Kotak bank, and I understood that they don't facilitate Direct-Plan for NRE to invest in Mutual fund. I am looking for the AMCs based on banks.

Anybody have any hints about Direct Plan for NREs using any banks ?